# about finding the diagonals of the rhombus given the angle

Tags: logic

suppose,only the angle of a rhombus is given then how can I find the length of the diagonals?(without measuring the side) Is there any equation where the angle is related to the diagonal only?

Comment: You can't. Knowing the angle of a rhombus determines the rhombus only up to similarity, since one can rescale the sides by a constant factor without changing any angles.

Comment: Let $a$ be the length of the rhombus' side and $\alpha$ be the given angle.  Applying the law of cosine you'll find the square of length of the diagonals to be $2a^2\pm 2a^2\cos(\alpha)$.